How to implement pagination for Apigee API response?
We have large volume of data that is to be returned by our API in Apigee. backend at denodo. when we make a call it is giving us this error message:
{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "Gateway Timeout",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "messaging.adaptors.http.flow.GatewayTimeout"
        }
    }
}

We are thinking to implement pagination for getting data. how can we  implement a partitioning system – splitting the response into pages and adding the necessary parameters in Apigee?
We want to

sending a call to check how many pages are there for our current filters.

sending a call for the 1st page, then another one for the 2nd page, and so on until we get all of the   data from the API


tried to check pagination in Apigee, but not sure how do we implement

Looks like the backend already supports pagination, why not ask the client to pass the pagination parameters? Implementing this on Apigee gateway doesn't look like a good practice to me. With that said, you may want to use the Javascript policy to do this - https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/javascript-object-model#makingjavascriptcalloutswithhttpclient
